# Doing an http post in vb.net can't see detail errors on iis 10

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-10

I have an aspx script and am trying to do an http post.

I was able to get a GET working to the resource that I want to use by doing:

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://222.222.100.1/api/webclient")
```

I was trying to do a post by doing:

```
 Using client As New Net.WebClient
  Dim postdata = client.UploadString("http://222.222.100.1/api/webclient", "age")
 End Using
```

I want to start with a simple test and build on it.  Is the client.UploadString the best thing to use?

I am also having major issues with getting errors to show.  When I have an error, I get the default internal server error page.

In my web root, I have a web config with

```
<customErrors mode="Detailed" /> 
<compilation debug="true" />
```

When I get the error, it shows customErrors mode="Off".  Why is iis 10 overriding what is in my web root?  I have access to the server and can change things, just don't know what to change and hours of search has yielded nothing.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I got the webrequest to work.  Still no luck on getting the errors to show.

Comment: You *probably want* customErrors mode=off

Comment: That did it.  Thanks a lot.  I have been stuck on that for a while   Hard to make progress without seeing the errors.  CustomErrors off seems counter intuitive.

Comment: Perhaps; custom error pages are *fancy error pages that you provide*, rather than letting ASP show it's usual Yellow Screen of Death with all the guts of your app, filesystem and structure etc. As such you either have them On (so everyone inc you, the developer, see the fancy pages no matter what), RemoteOnly (so that everyone sees the fancy pages because they make the request from some external place, but you, the dev, can see the YSOD if you make the request *on the webserver* itself) or Off (so that everyone, including all your customers, hackers etc, see the YSOD all the time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the webclient was that I needed the import "Imports System.Net".  The issue with the errors not showing was that I needed it to say customErrors="Off".